# BeautifulSoup не видит теги, вложенные в тег <h4>

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, lxml

Проблема описана в заголовке. Больше и сказать нечего. 2 дня бился на рабочем сайте - ничего понять не мог. В конце-концов создал минимально воспроизводимый пример.

Имеем HTML файл:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Что внутри тега h4 ?</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h4>
            111
            <p>(1880-1938)</p>
            222
            <p>Возчик артели возчиков, герой Русско-Японской и Первой мировой войн,
            полный Георгиевский кавалер;
            Расстрелян в г. Томске в 1938 году.</p>
            333
        </h4>
    </body>
</html>
```

И крохотную программку на Python, которая ведёт себя очень странно:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("index.html", "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'lxml')

    print(f"HTML:")
    print(f"Тег Н4 полностью: {soup.h4}")
    print(f"Имя тега: {soup.h4.name}")
    print(f"Текст внутри тега: {soup.h4.text}")
```

Попробуйте запустить программку. В качестве содержимого тега `<h4>` она покажет строку `111`. Т.е., содержимое тегов `<p>` не видно. Ладно, пусть так. Но и строки `222` и `333` тоже не видны! Мало того, если я вызову метод `.finf_all('p4')` то ничего не будет найдено!

Это что - ошибка в библиотеке? Или существует какой-то запрет на размещение любых тегов внутри тегов `<h?>`?

Comment: Интересно, что это за сайт, который оформляет заголовки подобным образом. Про прямой запрет со стороны `html` не скажу, но по семантике заголовок - это одна строка, отформатированная полностью одинаково, причём если на странице имеется несколько таких заголовков - все они форматируются одинаково. И заголовки учитываются поисковиками при индексировании. А здесь внутри заголовка появляются тэги абзаца. Как оно должно выглядеть? И что с таким заголовком делать поисковику? Обычно информацию, которая приведена во вложенных в `<h4>` тэгах, приводят ниже, отдельно от заголовка.

Comment: Пименяйте парсер, например 'lxml' ==> 'html.parser'

Comment: Дополню @maestro. На английском стаке есть ответ по поводу [тегов в heading теге](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53911664/17349246).

Comment: @maestro - "Интересно, что это за сайт" - Ну это всё делалось ещё в 90-е, на коленке...  Любителями. Сейчас подобные ресурсы не одобряются....

Comment: Попросту не валидный HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действительно, с `lxml` не работает. Для него тег `h4` закрыт до первого вложенного тега `p`:

```
html = """
...
</html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.body)
```

Результат:

```
<body>
<h4>
            111
            </h4><p>(1880-1938)</p>
...
```

Попробуйте с `html.parser` - с ним работает и он еще поставляется с питоном:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Что внутри тега h4 ?</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h4>
            111
            <p>(1880-1938)</p>
            222
            <p>Возчик артели возчиков, герой Русско-Японской и Первой мировой войн,
            полный Георгиевский кавалер;
            Расстрелян в г. Томске в 1938 году.</p>
            333
        </h4>
    </body>
</html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.body.h4.p)
# <p>(1880-1938)</p>

print(soup.find('h4').p)
# <p>(1880-1938)</p>

print(soup.select_one('h4 > p'))
# <p>(1880-1938)</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Этот код рабочий:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Что внутри тега h4 ?</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h4>
            111
            <p>(1880-1938)</p>
            222
            <p>Возчик артели возчиков, герой Русско-Японской и Первой мировой войн,
            полный Георгиевский кавалер;
            Расстрелян в г. Томске в 1938 году.</p>
            333
        </h4>
    </body>
</html>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
h4 = soup.find('h4')
for item in h4.findAll('p'):
    print(item)
```

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]